# Jest is not ignoring .hbs files

Tags: jestjs

Goal: To have Jest NOT run in .hbs files.

Attempted Solution: I tried including `"testPathIgnorePatterns": [".hbs"] in my config.json.

Error:

```
Test suite failed to run   
/Users/.../employee.hbs: Unexpected token (1:0)    
> 1 | <div class="employee">   
    | ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this modulePathIgnorePatterns

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulepathignorepatterns-array-string